# How to make Skydrive API return the url of a file?

Tags: javascript, html, api, onedrive

I want to log into SkyDrive from my website and access the library to choose a file and after pressing submit I want it to return the source url from that file.

So far, I managed to log into SkyDrive with the following files:

skydrive.html: http://pastebin.com/bnVNq5aZ 
helper.js: http://pastebin.com/pfaMYD7L

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using alert(file.source) instead of downloading.